# Exporting PDF with jspdf not rendering CSS

Tags: jquery, css, rendering, jspdf

I am using jspdf.debug.js to export different data from a website but there are a few problems, I can't get it to render the CSS in the exported PDF and if I have an image in the page I am exporting, the PDF returns blank...

Does anyone know a way to fix this ?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/9bqjyho1/6/) showing it's not rendering the CSS

And my script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#export').click(function(){
var d = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(/-/g, ""),
        filename = 'financiar_' + d + '.pdf',
        pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter'),
        specialElementHandlers = {
          '#editor': function( element, renderer ) {
              return true;
          }
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(
          $('.export').get(0) // HTML element
        , 25  // x coord
        , 25  // y coord
        , {
              'width': 550 // was 7.5, max width of content on PDF
            , elementHandlers: specialElementHandlers
        }
    );
    pdf.save( filename );
})
});
```

Comment: github issue with some advice on this is here https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/91

Comment: Solution by @amit-merin worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126963/jspdf-html2canvas-not-loaded-while-using-new-html-method/54180160#54180160

Comment: Solution by Amit Merin worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126963/jspdf-html2canvas-not-loaded-while-using-new-html-method/54180160#54180160

Answer (score 36):

As I know jsPDF is not working with CSS and the same issue I was facing.

To solve this issue, I used [Html2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). Just **Add HTML2Canvas JS** and then use `pdf.addHTML()` instead of `pdf.fromHTML()`.

Here's my code (no other code):

```
 var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
 pdf.addHTML($('#ElementYouWantToConvertToPdf')[0], function () {
     pdf.save('Test.pdf');
 });
```

Best of Luck!

**Edit:** Refer to [this line](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/270/#issuecomment-106708016) in case you didn't find `.addHTML()`

Comment: Hmm, I'll be looking into it, but as far as I can see, it only outputs the CSS1 from the stylesheet. Hmm, I'm digging into it a bit.

Comment: How can I remove black background and improve output quality?

Comment: Hi for some reason my printed PDF only has half of it, left part. I followed your instructions by adding the scripts, using pdf.addHTML() instead of pdf.fromHTML(). Any hint? Thanks

Comment: This will not work for long image. If the image/content are more than one page.

Comment: @mihir
Please, it worked with me, but there are problems with Arabic language formate! Any help

Comment: @Hana90 What's the issue?

Comment: such like this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701878/convert-html-page-containing-arabic-characters-to-pdf-using-flyingsaucer

Comment: Thanks, I can handle it by create image within canvas containing Arabic text, then when converting to pdf, there is image rather than text :) such like this example

Comment: addHTML is not a function, I have added HTML2Canvas JS as well.. and even no such function in jspdf..

Comment: Do you know how to fix the problem if pdf file look blurry? I used the exact same code from the answer above. The file is generated but looks blurry.

Comment: Not sure but can you try this another HTML structure because maybe it can be from html structure?

Comment: @nullpointer, Add the background-color:white to the element's css you'd like to export.

Answer (score 17):

jspdf does not work with css but it can work along with html2canvas. You can use jspdf along with html2canvas.

include these two files in script on your page :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function genPDF()
  {
   html2canvas(document.body,{
   onrendered:function(canvas){

   var img=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   var doc = new jsPDF();
   doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',20,20);
   doc.save('test.pdf');
   }

   });

  }
  </script>
```

You need to download script files such as 
https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jspdf

make clickable button on page so that it will generate pdf and it will be seen same as that of original html page.

```
<a href="javascript:genPDF()">Download PDF</a>
```

It will work perfectly.

Comment: But this method will not generate native PDF It will only convert image to pdf

Answer (score 7):

Slight change to @rejesh-yadav wonderful answer.

html2canvas now returns a promise.

```html
html2canvas(document.body).then(function (canvas) {
    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, 10);
    doc.save('test.pdf');        
});
```

Hope this helps some!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the example of css implemented html to pdf conversion using jspdf on following link:
[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh13yadav/cdmgmfqf/1/)

This is sample code for the jspdf html to pdf download.

```
$('#print-btn').click(() => {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
    pdf.addHTML(document.body,function() {
        pdf.save('web.pdf');
    });
})
```

Comment: It could be because in fiddler we do not have much access change background but if you could implement the same on your code you can change the background with css properties.

Comment: Thanks. Although the generated pdf doesn't have the clearer font. Can this be fixed? or is it browser issue?

Comment: Thanks. Although the generated pdf doesn't have the clearer font. Can this be fixed? or is it browser issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is sample what I used to add external CSS in HTML, I have external CSS file and link to HTML as normal and get the main element in javascript file then generate the pdf through following code.

```
htmlString = document.getElementById("main");
pdf.addHTML(htmlString, function () {
   pdf.save('Test.pdf');
```

});

Answer (score 0):

set option useCSS:true

in typescript:
autoTable(doc, { html: '#mytable',useCss:true });

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -13):

To remove black background only add background-color: white; to the style of