# Export HTML + CSS to PDF using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf-generation, jspdf

I want to export a part of my html code to pdf, for this I am using the following code :

```
<script language = "JAVASCRIPT">
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
    }
};
$('#download').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#mytable').html(), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
</script>
```

but it doesn't support CSS .. how can I export it with its style ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting PDF with jspdf not rendering CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946275/exporting-pdf-with-jspdf-not-rendering-css)

Answer (score 0):

What data do you want to export?

If you want to export an HTML `<table>`, you can take a look at [this export sample](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/export-to-pdf) provided by the Shield UI Grid widget.