# Keeping CSS in Html to PDF export using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I am trying to generate PDF using JavaScript but I am unable to generate on with CSS. I am currently using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). The issue with jsPDF is that it takes away all the formatting. I don't need styles or colors but I need to have multiple `divs` side by side.

My code is

```
                    margins = {
                        top: 0,
                        bottom: 0,
                        left: 20,
                        width: 170
                    };                       
                    pdf.setFontSize(6);
                    pdf.fromHTML(
                        $('#textpdfdiv').html(), 
                        margins.left, 
                        margins.top, { 
                            'width': margins.width
                        },

                        function (dispose) {                                
                            pdf.save('Export_Text.pdf');
                        }, margins
                    );
```

`textpdfdiv` is an id of `div` that has all the values of form in separate `divs` side by side. But when I generate PDF, they go into separate row.

I can't use [XEPOnline](https://github.com/Xportability/css-to-pdf) because it processes online.

How I need PDF output is something like this (minus the colors and form fields etc)

[image]

**The output that I currently have is**

[image]

Is there any plugin that converts HTML+CSS to PDF? Or can I achieve this with jsPDF? I don't have a table so this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369661/export-html-css-to-pdf-using-javascript) doesn't help as well.

**EDIT:** I can't use Html2Canvas as well because it creates long non searchable PDFs and I need searchable PDFs. Html2Canvas takes screenshot and it is an image but I need text that can be copied.

Thank you,
Hamza

Comment: I assume this needs to happen automatically?  I only ask because the only way I know how is to format your CSS with `@print` media query and actually print the page (output to PDF).  I'm sure this doesn't help, but maybe this can get you to the right track?

Comment: no actually print doesn't help... because it doesn't support all browsers secondly I only need few things.. this creates over 50 MB of PDF

Comment: Any solution you found?

Answer (score 5):

I used this plugin to generate PDF with HTML and CSS. You just have to include the content, you want to put in PDF, in a "" with an id.

https://github.com/Xportability/css-to-pdf

Comment: Is this free to use?

Answer (score 0):

maybe i could not to be of such help, but it seems to be a bug of that library: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/91

In that page you'll find a suggestion for your purpose: to use Html2Canvas.

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't help.. I have used that as well and Html2Canvas creates long non search able PDFs, I need searchable PDFs. Html2Canvas basically takes screenshot and it is an image not text..