# jsPDF: html2canvas not loaded while using new .html() method

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

I want to use [jsPDF.html](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to convert html page to pdf, and I'm using this code:

```js
savePdf () {
  var pdf = new jsPDF({unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' })
  pdf.html(document.getElementById('printable-cv'), {
    callback: function (pdf) {
      pdf.save('cv-a4.pdf');
    }
  })
}
```

but I get error `html2canvas not loaded`: is it something I forgot? I do have html2canvas

> "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12"

I'm using vuejs with webpack.

In the same page I'm currently using alternatively [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) with the following code:

```js
savePdf0 () {
  let opt = {
    filename: 'cv.pdf',
    enableLinks: true,
    image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
    html2canvas: {
      scale: 8,
      useCORS: true,
      width: 310,
      letterRendering: true,
    },
    jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
  }
  html2pdf().set(opt).from(document.getElementById('printable-cv')).save()
}
```

that correcly finds html2canvas.

What does `html2canvas not loaded` really mean? what can I do to load it?

Comment: I added a codesandbox that shows the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/6vmqpwy0xr

Answer (score 27, accepted):

jsPDF needs html2canvas to be declared in the global scope to work, so you have to write

```
window.html2canvas = html2canvas;
```

somewhere before you call `html()`.

That said, I wasn't able to make it work either, so I resorted to [a wrapper](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) that works around the issue by calling manually `html2canvas()` then giving the resulting canvas to jsPDF.

Comment: You made my week!!! :D Thanks wo/man! But now I can't set the right fit for the a4 size. It's either tiny or huge :(  Any clue?

Comment: Thanks. working on my react app

Answer (score 5):

Following the previous anser by [ptidus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4132005/ptidus), this should work:

```
saveAsPdf() {
  window.html2canvas = html2canvas;
  var doc = new jsPDF(
    'p', 'pt', 'a4'
  );
  doc.html(document.querySelector("body"), {
    callback: function(pdf) {
      pdf.save("cv-a4.pdf");
    }
  });
}
```

There is something off with the margins probably, but I didn't explore that too much.
You will also notice that the generated PDF is actually text and not an image.

[code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zro4v69kp3)

Comment: If using TypeScript it won't be happy with window.html2canvas so just do an ugly window["html2canvas"] = html2canvas.

Answer (score 2):

For all of you who are using `webpack` what I did is I added `html2canvas` to a `ProvidePlugin`. [You can read about this here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/)

```js
// webpack configuration
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        html2canvas: 'html2canvas'
    });
]
```

Comment: that's working plus the as correct marked answer while i do use webpack

Answer (score 1):

I had luck **loading html2canvas separately**:

The below example **saves a .pdf** (check downloads) containing "Hello World" rendered from a canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        //1). draw 
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "white"
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.strokeText("Hello World", 10, 50);

        
        //2).save as pdf
               const doc = new jspdf.jsPDF({ unit: 'pt' }); 

            doc.html(document.body, {
                callback: (pdf) => {
                    pdf.save('MyPdfFile.pdf')
                }
            });
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:3px solid red;">
    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following two had fixed the issue:

1. // webpack configuration
   plugins: [
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   html2canvas: 'html2canvas'
   });
   ]
2. window["html2canvas"] = html2canvas;

even with out the first step its working.