# How to convert HTML Application into PDF and send it to Ajax POST call as multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdf, sapui5

I'm facing an issue in converting my HTML page to pdf and sending to `Ajax` **POST** as `multipart/form-data`..
After checking in many pages, I came to know that using `jsPDF` plugin we can achieve.

But using `jsPDF` we have to convert `HTML` into jpg(in base64 format) and then it can be downloaded to PDF.

But I want to convert into **PDF** format and that converted PDF needs to be sent to `Ajax` **POST** as `multipart/form-data`.

Below is the code I'm trying with...

```
<script>
var mywindow = window.open();
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Convert to PDF</title>');
mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
mywindow.document.write('<p>Convert this Page to PDF and send it to Ajax POST as Form</p>');
mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

html2canvas(mywindow.document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0);//This is converting into jpg format in base64 format, But i want base64 in pdf format.
        doc.save('test.pdf'); // This is to save in local system(After getting downloaded, PDF is not displaying properly, It is very clumsy)
        
        var form = new FormData();
        var blob = new Blob([img.split(",")[1]], {
            type: "pdf"
        }); // Here im trying to convert jpg to pdf But that is not working
        form.append("file", blob, "FSM.pdf");
        form.append("fileName", "FSM.pdf");
        form.append("description", "12");
        
        
        
        $.ajax({
            "url": "my_URL",
            "method": "POST",
            "timeout": 0,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            },
            "processData": false,
            "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
            "contentType": false,
            "data": form,
            success: function(res) {
                var res;
            },
            error: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Can someone please help me to resolve my issue? I need to send PDF to `Ajax` **POST** as `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert the image to base64 and then to Blob and send it to the server. When you use base64 images, a lot of lines will be sent to server. With blob, it's only the file.

You can use this code bellow:

```js
function dataURLtoBlob(dataURL) {
  let array, binary, i, len;
  binary = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1]);
  array = [];
  i = 0;
  len = binary.length;
  while (i < len) {
    array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    i++;
  }
  return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
    type: 'image/png'
  });
};
```

And canvas code here:

```js
const file = dataURLtoBlob( canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0) );
```

After that you can use ajax with Form:

```js
const fd = new FormData;

fd.append('image', file);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/url-to-save',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for doing this is via a external library like jsPDF and then send the blob data in a Form to the backend similar to submit.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <!-- CDN jsPDF -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Button to send AJAX -->
  <button id="btn" onclick="javascript:send()">Send Doc via AJAX</button>
  <script>
    function send() {
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.fromHTML('<h1>Hello World!</h1>', 20, 20);

      var formData = new FormData();
      var blob = new Blob([doc.output("blob")], { type: "application/pdf" });
      formData.append("file", blob, "document.pdf");

      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", "/upload");
      request.send(formData);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

I am not sure the printWindow has any API to do the above.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It worked for me. But why my CSS is not getting applied to the html code doc.fromHTML('<h1>Hello World!</h1>', 20, 20);?

Comment: If your requirement was to add CSS as well, I would suggest to check [Exporting PDF with jspdf not rendering CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946275/exporting-pdf-with-jspdf-not-rendering-css) as well

Comment: i checked the link that you shared. html2canvas() that needs to be used to load the CSS, But even that was not working properly..PDF didnt downloaded properly alignment was not proper and it was clumsy. Is there any other solution that can fix this issue?